# Cannot call COM object created from STAThread from oher STA threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, com, interop, marshalling

I am new to COM and trying to understand the difference between STA and MTA. I tried to create an example that would show that COM can manage calls to object created in STA that is not thread-safe.

`MyCalcServer` class here is created using ATL Simple Object. The settings used are the same as in [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/SimpleCOM.aspx):

- **Threading Model:** Apartment
- **Aggregation:** No
- **Interface:** Custom

`MyCalcServer` COM object is used in another C# project which is:

```
class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyCOMLib.MyCalcServer instance = new MyCOMLib.MyCalcServer();
        string output1;
        instance.ChangeValue("Gant", out output1);
        Console.WriteLine(output1);


        Thread t1 = new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                string output;
                instance.ChangeValue("Gant", out output);
                Console.WriteLine(output);
            }
        });
        t1.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        t1.Start();

        // :
        // also has t2 and t3 here with similar code
        // :

        t1.Join(); t2.Join(); t3.Join();

    }
}
```

However, this always results in `InvalidCastException` (E_NOINTERFACE) raised inside t1's code. I have also tried changing ApartmentState to MTA with no success.

> Unable to cast COM object of type
>   'MyCOMLib.MyCalcServerClass' to
>   interface type
>   'MyCOMLib.IMyCalcServer'. This
>   operation failed because the
>   QueryInterface call on the COM
>   component for the interface with IID
>   '{B005DB8C-7B21-4898-9DEC-CBEBE175BB21}'
>   failed due to the following error: No
>   such interface supported (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x80004002
>   (E_NOINTERFACE)).

Could anybody please explain what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Maybe the JIT thinks you are not using "instance" and releases it early.

try to put Marshal.ReleaseComObject(instance) after the joins.

Comment: @adrianm Still not working but thanks for this

Comment: Try to change the first line to MyCOMLib.IMyCalcServer instance = new MyCOMLib.MyCalcServer();

I think only interfaces (not classes) can be marshalled between threads.

Comment: @adiranm Still got the same exception. Luckily I got this solved. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: +1 for the question, I just hit the same thing. I knew it was due to cross-thread calls on an apartment object, but I didn't understand why the exception complained about casting the object. Now I know - it must look for marshalling support during the cast, and doesn't find it, so gives a generic error. Could be more helpful...

Comment: m3rLinEz - what was the solution to this?

Comment: @tofutim Check my answer in this thread (http://stackoverflow.com/a/2182075/12460.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You explicitly ask COM to create instance for main thread, then you pass this to another thread. Of course in some circumstance it is allowed (for example declare MyCalcServer as multithread).

But in your case it looks you need create proxy for another thread. In regular COM clients it is done by CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream. There is large article to clarify it http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/cominterop.aspx

Comment: The .Net wrapper does the marshaling between threads automatically (otherwise the finalizer wouldn't work).
If the automatic marshal didn't work the error would be E_WRONG_THREAD (8001010E)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get this resolve.

As I'm new to COM, I don't know much about Proxy/Stub and that they're needed for marshaling stuffs between STA and STA. After created a new ATL project and make sure I have "Merge Proxy/Stub" ticked. The problem vanished.

I find the info from this page useful: [Why would I want to merge Proxy/Stub code with my DLL project.](http://www.dotnetheaven.com/Uploadfile/prvn_131971/merge_proxy04232005000606AM/merge_proxy.aspx)

> Proxy/stubs providing standard
>   marshaling for your component. In many
>   cases a DLL-based component may not
>   need proxy/stub because it is running
>   in the same context of its client, and
>   this option may seem useless at first.
>   However, COM uses the marshaling
>   process to synchronize access to a
>   component in multi-threaded
>   situations. So, a DLL-based component
>   will need a proxy/stub DLL in at least
>   two cases:
>
> - It's running a multi-threaded client and needs to pass interface
>     pointer between apartments (STA to STA
>     or MTA to STA).
> - DCOM can provide a surrogate process for a DLL-based component so
>     that it can be accessed in a
>     distributed environment. In this case
>     a proxy/stub is needed to marshal
>     between machines.
>
> By merging the proxy/stub code with
>   your implementation, you don't have to
>   distribute two DLLs, just the one.

I will mark @Dewfy's answer as accept as he has shed some light on the Proxy topic.