# Calling COM object from STA thread cause TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED on some machines

Tags: c#, multithreading, com, add-in, office-interop

I am developing Word shared add-in, using COM shim wizard.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mshneer/archive/2010/03/19/com-shim-wizards-for-vs-2010.aspx

Everything worked fine until I tried to use some threads.
It fail on some machines with TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED exception for COM-object created in main thread.

I have a Word document object (_doc) from some Word event and try to use from STA thread like this:

```
Word.Document _doc;
void Start()
{
    _mainLoopThread = new Thread(MainLoop);
    _mainLoopThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    _mainLoopThread.IsBackground = true;
    _mainLoopThread.Start();
}
void MainLoop()
{
    // some code...
    Word.Range r = _doc.StoryRanges[Word.WdStoryType.wdMainTextStory];
    // some code...
}
```

Everything works fine on my dev machine, on test machine and for most of users. However for some user it fails with exception:
Unable to cast COM object of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.DocumentClass' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{0002096B-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED)).

The only way we were able to reproduce it - is to install Office 2013, then remove it and install Office 2007. I checked registry, but didn't found any registration problems for this guid. I tried tool from MS, that should clear leftovers from Office 2013, 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2739501
but it didn't help.

This is not registration problem, because I can use same _doc object from main thread without any errors.
In rgs-file for COM-shim I use STA model 
    InprocServer32 = s '%MODULE%'
    {
        val ThreadingModel = s 'Apartment'
    }
I also set CLR mode as STA in Properties-Linker-Advanced, but this didn't help.

I tried to use CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream, as suggested here
[Cannot call COM object created from STAThread from oher STA threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175419/cannot-call-com-object-created-from-stathread-from-oher-sta-threads)
but failed to make it work even on my dev machine.
Here is the code:
        [DllImport("ole32.dll")]
        static extern int CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream([In] ref Guid riid, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] object pUnk, out IStream ppStm);

```
    IStream _docForThreadStream = null;

    Guid _docInterfaceGuid;

    void InitDocForThread()
    {            
        object[] attr = _doc.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(GuidAttribute), false);
        GuidAttribute g = (GuidAttribute)attr[0];
        _docInterfaceGuid = new Guid(g.Value);

        CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream(ref _docInterfaceGuid, Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(_doc), out _docForThreadStream);
    }

    [DllImport("ole32.dll")]
    static extern int CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream(IStream pStm, [In] ref Guid riid, out object ppv);

    Word.Document _docForThread = null;

    void MainLoop()
    {
            object pDoc;
            int hr = CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream(_docForThreadStream, ref _docInterfaceGuid, out pDoc);
            // _docForThreadStream != null, hr == E_NOINTERFACE
     }
```

CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream gives me E_NOINTERFACE when I try to get object from IStream. Can anyone send me link with working example for C#? I googled, but found only some examples for C++.

It seems that Office COM registration get coorrupted such a way that it works for same thread (add-in running in same thread as office), but fails to get marshalled to another STA thread...

Answer (score -1):

Just recently, we watched the very same case: TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED when making calls to the Word object model in a thread. You must use any Office object model in the main thread only. Please find some info and further links at http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2010/11/04/threads-managed-office-extensions/.

Comment: COM doesn't have the notion of a main thread. COM implements its threading model by apartments. A process can have any number of STA's and at most one MTA. An object instance belongs to a single apartment only. The Office Object Model exposes STA objects. Each object lives in an STA and can only be accessed from the STA that created it. This is really basic COM. The link you posted is entirely vague, and since the author doesn't know COM, the recommendations are misleading as well. See [Understanding and Using COM Threading Models](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809971.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The discussion above relates to COM add-ins, not to pure COM. Because a COM add-in should comply with the rules dictated by its host application. Specifically, it should use the host application's object model on the application's main thread. Please find more details at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8sesy69e.aspx. Hope this helps.

Comment: You have things backwards: A *COM add-in* must adhere to what you call *pure COM* rules. There is no distinction. The link you posted in your previous comment spells out pure COM rules. Nothing of this is specific to Office add-ins. The document merely leaves out those rules, that are not interesting for Office add-in development. The link you posted in your answer talks about concurrency in COM, without using the term *apartment*. That alone makes it incomplete, at best, and gives reason to believe, that the author doesn't have "Essential COM" by Don Box in their book shelf.

Comment: You have the right to look at things as you like. The reality is: regardless of what books Microsoft read, they explicitly state that your COM add-in may not work if it uses the object model on a thread other than the host application's main thread. Here's a citation from that page: "When a background thread makes a call to the Office application, the call is automatically marshaled across the STA boundary. However, there is no guarantee that the Office application can handle the call at the time the background thread makes it."

Comment: *"Your COM add-in may not work if it uses the object model on the thread other than the host application's main thread."* That's not what it says, anywhere. There is no such thing as a *main thread*. COM's concurrency model is based on apartments. You can only access an STA object from the STA that created it. You are talking about *threads* when you should be referring to *apartments*. All of this is explained in Don Box' [Essential COM](http://www.amazon.com/Essential-COM-Don-Box/dp/0201634465). An absolute must read, if you plan to become proficient in COM.